# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while adding an element to ArrayList without mentioning index

Tags: java

I am facing a strange issue which is very random. When my code tries to add an entry in ArrayList it throws ArrayOutOfBoundsException. my arraylist does not have fixed size and I do not even add element at specific location. I am trying to add data with just simple add() method. I have never come accross such situation. Anyone who can help me on this?

Exception:

```
Exception occured in TestWebService :: _treatRequest() :java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 10
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:487)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:499)
at com.ds.ct.kt.scalaclient.helpers.TestRequestPoolSingleton.addToLaunched(TestRequestPoolSingleton.java:87)
at com.ds.ct.kt.TestWebService ._executeRecurrentLaunch(TestWebService .java:200)
at com.ds.ct.kt.TestWebService ._executeRecurrentCall(TestWebService .java:158)
at com.ds.ct.kt.TestWebService ._treatRequest(TestWebService .java:130)
at com.ds.ct.kt.TestWebService .doGet(TestWebService .java:87)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:554)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:600)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:772)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
at com.el.ap.instance.rpc.RegularSynchronizationQueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(RegularSynchronizationQueuedThreadPool.java:550)
```

And it is getting thrown from below piece of code:

```
    String requestID = _getRequestID(iRequest);
    String requestLaunchType = _getRequestLaunchType(iRequest);
    Map<String, List<String>>_launchedRequestsMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    List<String> requestList = _launchedRequestsMap.get(requestLaunchType);
    requestList.add(requestID);
```

Here, requestID can be blank or have string values but it will never be null. Proper checks are performed.

Comment: Show the full stacktrace

Comment: Is this list being modified by multiple threads by any chance? `ArrayList` isn't thread-safe.

Comment: Yup, has all the smells for multi-threaded access: occurs "randomly", doesn't seem possible when looking at the code and yet it happens with some regularity.

Comment: The simplest "solution" is to replace your `ArrayList` with a `CopyOnWriteList`, but really you probably need to review your code for unsynchronized access to shared data structures and fix/redesign them, because odds are this is not the only potential source for problems.

Comment: In the stacktrace the method call `TestRequestPoolSingleton.addToLaunched()` is another hint that this is caused by multi-threaded access to an `ArrayList`